# Redis delete hash keys by pattern in hash value

Tags: shell, command-line, redis

I am stuck with a little problem. I want to delete all hash key/value pairs from a redis database where the value matches a string pattern. I found some solutions for the command line for the problem of deleting hashes by key value, but none for the related problem of deleting by value pattern.

concrete example:

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "Wild"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "Window"
(integer) 1
```

Now I want to remove all key/value pairs from myhash that match "Wi.*", i.e. field1/Wild, field3/Window, but leave field2/World untouched.

I would like to do this on the command line, so something like this would be great:

```
redis-cli -n 0 KEYS someFoo* | xargs redis-cli -n 0 DEL
```

The above works of course not for hashes. So in the end I need to call

```
redis-cli -n 0 hdel myhash field1 
redis-cli -n 0 hdel myhash field3
```

in an automated manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the only way you can accomplish this is with `HGETALL`, or even better `HSCAN`.

```
redis> HGETALL myhash
1) "field1"
2) "Wild"
3) "field2"
4) "Window"
```

You could in theory pipe that into something that matches even lines with your regex and issues one or more HDEL commands with the odd line preceding matches. That is a bit much for my bash skills. Perhaps a lua script would be easier.

You really should use `HSCAN` if your hash is very large. `HGETALL` will block while it gets the data.

Comment: Yes thanks, but my CLI skills are also not that good and I was really looking for such a solution. About HSCAN, yes that is a good idea, since the hash in question has a couple of million entries.

Comment: For something this complicated it would probably be easiest to write a little script in whatever language you are most comfortable with.